# C# How to Display platform target

Tags: c#

How to display platform target.

I have an .net window form which is compiled for x86 os how? do i display platform target on a label.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ks35f6y.aspx) might help you, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228958.aspx) has the list of contents to help you display what you need.

Comment: Good find but I believe this is for extending Visual Studio. I don't believe it is accessible from a running application.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for 32 bit vs 64 bit you can check the size of an IntPtr (it will be either 32 bits or 64 bits as per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx)).

```
public static string Platform
{
    get 
    {
        if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
            return "x64";
        else
            return "x86";
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is much better. For one thing, it does not point to an external source which can get broken over time (like the accepted answer does).

Comment: But what if I want to know whether it be `AnyCPU` or not?